# Can't get React http-proxy-middleware to work

Tags: reactjs, http-proxy-middleware

I've struggled for hours now trying to get http-proxy-middleware to work but what ever I do it just won't work.

This is my setUp.js file (located in src)

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use(
        createProxyMiddleware('/api', {
            target: 'http://catfact.ninja/fact',
            changeOrigin: true,
            pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' },
            logLevel: 'debug',
        })
    );
};
```

Here is how I fetch

```
  fetch('/api', {
    method: 'GET',
  })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      response.json()
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log('Success: ', data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error: ', error);
    });
```

During start and fetching I get these messages

```
[HPM] Proxy created: /api  -> http://catfact.ninja/fact
[HPM] Proxy rewrite rule created: "^/api" ~> ""
[HPM] Subscribed to http-proxy events: [ 'error', 'close' ]
Starting the development server...

Compiled successfully!

You can now view app in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.0.90:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

webpack compiled successfully
[HPM] Rewriting path from "/api" to ""
[HPM] GET /api ~> http://catfact.ninja/fact
[HPM] Rewriting path from "/api" to ""
[HPM] GET /api ~> http://catfact.ninja/fact
```

This is the error I get Chrome's console

[Console with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwGmG.png)

When using the "proxy" setting in package.json it works fine but since I need to add proxy for a websocket as well I need to use the setupProxy.js file.

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, I've searched for a solution for a very long time and nothing I do gets me closer to figuring out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Apparently there is a bug in "pathRewrite" in the current version of http-proxy-middleware which causes it not to work properly. This is fixed in the next version according to the developer.

Comment: Is there a workaround till then?